# Jquery: position buttons below current table row

Tags: html, jquery

I am trying to position two buttons **below** the currently active table row's `TD`. I want them to look like this:

[image]

I have tried several dozen methods but none produces the desired result: either the buttons don't appear at all, or they appear **after** the currently active `TD`, or after all table rows.

The only working (kind of) method I've found is this:

```
$(this).next().prepend(buttons);
```

But the result is not particularly aesthetic:
[image]
[image]

The exact same result is accomplished with:

```
$(this).next().append(buttons);
```

If I use

```
$(this).append(buttons);
```

The buttons are inserted *inside* the cell I'm editing and their HTML gets saved, too, so this doesn't work.

I even tried creating a special empty `TD` in the next table row (`<td class="controls"></td>`), into which to insert the buttons, but I can't find the correct code to target that particular cell and no others. This approach is, however, not the best as the buttons will appear in the first cell on the next row for both the source and target cells. My ultimate goal is to accomplish what is displayed on the first screenshot: the buttons should appear immediately below the currently active cell.

Here are some of the jQuery methods I've tried:

```
$(this).next('td.controls').append(buttons); /* nothing is displayed */
$(this).next('tr td.controls').append(buttons); /* nothing is displayed */
$(this).parent().append(buttons); /* the buttons appear after and outide the table */
$(this).parent().prepend(buttons); /* the buttons appear before the first cell on the active row */
$(this).parent().next().prepend(buttons); /* the buttons are inserted inside the `td.controls` cell but for both the source and the target */
```

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cheeseus/cf5qkba7/4/

I hope I've provided all relevant details and code. If not, let me know.

Comment: Why not just reposition `<div class="edit-controls" contenteditable="false"><button class="edit-ok btn btn-sm btn-success">SAVE</button> <button class="edit-cancel btn btn-sm btn-danger">CANCEL</button></div>` after `</table>`? Why use `js` for positioned `html`elements? Just asking.

Comment: @Raky, it's a long table: the user can choose to display 25 or 50 or 100 rows. If I position the buttons at the bottom of the table, it's very inconvenient. That's why I want the buttons to only appear below the cell being edited at the moment and be hidden when not editing cell contents (because there are many other actions the user can do).

Comment: Oh, You are intending to create in-line edit html table and the buttons must appear for the row which is under edit mode. Correct?

Comment: @Raky, yes, correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use JQuery [`find`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) method.

> Given a jQuery object that represents a set of DOM elements, the .find() method allows us to search through the descendants of these elements in the DOM tree and construct a new jQuery object from the matching elements.

```
$(this).parent().next().find("td:eq(" + $(this).index() + ").read-only").prepend(buttons); /* display the Save and Cancel buttons */
```

Above js code will find the next `td` at current index of `.read-only` class and insert the buttons *before* it.

I have also added following CSS to correctly position the buttons in single row:

```
.edit-controls {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

#### Check the following example:

```js
$('.editor').dblclick(function() {

  active = $(this); /* assign current segment to a variable */

  buttons = '<div class="edit-controls" contenteditable="false"><button class="edit-ok btn btn-sm btn-success">SAVE</button> <button class="edit-cancel btn btn-sm btn-danger">CANCEL</button></div>';

  $('.edit-controls').remove(); /* remove the Save and Cancel buttons if already displayed in other cells */
  $('.editor').prop('contenteditable', 'false'); /* make any active editable cells inactive */
  $('.editor').removeClass('border border-success'); /* remove green border around cell that indicates active editable state */
  $(this).prop('contenteditable', 'true'); /* make the clicked cell active editable */
  $(this).addClass('border border-success'); /* display green border around active editable cell */

  $(this).parent().next().find("td:eq(" + $(this).index() + ").read-only").prepend(buttons); /* display the Save and Cancel buttons */

  originalContent = $(this).html(); /* store original content to use if user clicks Cancel */

  $('.edit-cancel').click(function() {
    active.html(originalContent); /* restore original content */
    active.prop('contenteditable', 'false'); /* remove editable state */
    active.removeClass('border border-success'); /* remove editable border */
    $('.edit-controls').remove(); /* remove the Save and Cancel buttons */
  });

});
```

```css
.edit-controls {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-xOolHFLEh07PJGoPkLv1IbcEPTNtaed2xpHsD9ESMhqIYd0nLMwNLD69Npy4HI+N" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="col-lg-11 col-sm-12 ms-lg-3 ms-sm-1 mt-4 table-responsive">
  <table class="table table-sm table-striped table-hover caption-top editable" id="editable">
    <thead class="table-dark">
      <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Source</th>
        <th>Target</th>
        <th><i class="bi bi-braces-asterisk"></i></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td class="editor" data-segmentID="1" data-fileName="sample_tmx.tmx" data-id="sourceText[1]">&lt;bpt x=&quot;1&quot; i=&quot;1&quot; type=&quot;italic&quot;/&gt;Формантът -лар/-лар- (от тюрк. -lar) е слабо представен в българската словообразувателна система.&lt;ept i=&quot;1&quot;/&gt;</td>
        <td class="editor" data-segmentID="1" data-fileName="sample_tmx.tmx" data-id="targetText[1]">&lt;bpt x=&quot;1&quot; i=&quot;1&quot; type=&quot;italic&quot;/&gt;The -lar/-lar- formant (from the Turkic -lar) is sparsely represented in the Bulgarian word-building system.&lt;ept i=&quot;1&quot;/&gt;</td>
        <td class="read-only"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="table-secondary small">
        <td class="controls"></td>
        <td class="read-only">Created: 2020-11-01 @ 13:37:34 by Cheeseus</td>
        <td class="read-only">Modified: by TMX Editor</td>
        <td class="read-only" id="status-report-1"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td class="editor" data-segmentID="2" data-fileName="sample_tmx.tmx" data-id="sourceText[2]">ПАРТНЬОРИ</td>
        <td class="editor" data-segmentID="2" data-fileName="sample_tmx.tmx" data-id="targetText[2]">PARTNERS</td>
        <td class="read-only"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="table-secondary small">
        <td class="controls"></td>
        <td class="read-only">Created: 2008-08-12 @ 11:12:21 by Cheeseus</td>
        <td class="read-only">Modified: by Cheeseus</td>
        <td class="read-only" id="status-report-2"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, @samnoon! This works – even without the CSS. That's one rather complicated piece of jQuery for a newbie like me.